# Text blur on print laravel invoice package which is based on DOMPDF

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

Hi I have created a pdf with Laravel invoice package now the pdf showing in the display is fine but when printing that document fonts get blurred anyone please guide how to solve it??[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text color should be black. that is why it was happening